# css/scss: при наведении на один элемент подсвечивать

Tags: css, классы, scss, hover, атрибуты

есть набор `<span>` у которых проставлены атрибуты `attr-id`

```
<span attr-id='1'>X</span> <span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='1'>Z</span>
```

можно ли в css реализовать следующий функционал

при наведении мышки на `span` выставляются свойства (т.е. свойство `:hover`) не только этот `span`, но и все у которых тот же самый `attr-id`, что и у него

например если навели на `<span attr-id='1'>X</span>`, то `background-color: red` должен выставиться и для `<span attr-id='1'>Z</span>` потому что у них одинаковые `attr-id`, т.е. красный фон должен появиться сразу у двух `span`

Comment: если оно нужно "еще вчера" (ждать когда все обновятся до `:has`а некогда)... вот так наугад, не видя имеющейся верстки со стилями, `[attr-id=1]:hover ~ [attr-id=1]{backgroud: red}` самое приличное что приходит на ум(разумеется подсветятся только те, которые в потоке находятся ниже тригера). можно еще их родителю фон менять с `background-clip: content` в комплекте... или попытаться поизвращаться, скажем с svg use в качестве фона... крч верстку в студию.

Answer (score 5):

Если уникальных значений немного, то относительно новый псевдокласс [`:has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) позволяет легко организовать искомое поведение:

```css
:root:has([attr-id='1']:hover) [attr-id='1'], 
:root:has([attr-id='2']:hover) [attr-id='2'], 
:root:has([attr-id='3']:hover) [attr-id='3'] { 
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<span attr-id='1'>X</span> <span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='3'>Z</span>
<span attr-id='3'>Z</span> <span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='1'>X</span>
<span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='3'>Z</span> <span attr-id='1'>X</span>
```

Если нужна поддержка старых браузеров, то можете воспользоваться "костылём" из [второго варианта ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1557353/265406).

---

Если допускаются скрипты...

> Т.е. придется отслеживать наведение на один элемент, выставление классов всем нужным элементам, отслеживать отведение от элемента и сброса классов со всем нужных элементов - так?

Можно пойти следующим путём:

```js
const styleHighlight = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).sheet;
document.addEventListener('mouseover', (ev) => {
  styleHighlight.insertRule(`[attr-id='${ev.target.attributes["attr-id"].value}']{background-color: red}`, 0);
});
document.addEventListener('mouseout', (ev) => {
  styleHighlight.deleteRule(0);
});
```

```html
<span attr-id='1'>X</span> <span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='3'>Z</span>
<span attr-id='3'>Z</span> <span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='1'>X</span>
<span attr-id='2'>Y</span> <span attr-id='3'>Z</span> <span attr-id='1'>X</span>
```

Comment: уникальных значений к сожалению может быть очень много - сотни

Comment: @Zhihar, тогда один лишь CSS не поможет. Только скрипт.

Comment: надеялся, что можно будет обойтись малой кровью. Т.е. придется отслеживать наведение на один элемент, выставление классов всем нужным элементам, отслеживать отведение от элемента и сброса классов со всем нужных элементов - так? :(

Comment: Покажите пример вашего html.... У вас может быть намного проще решение чем вы ищете.

Comment: @Zhihar, приведите наконец более показательный пример верстки, там и видно будет, можно ли что то сделать и если да то что именно. иерархия будет плоская?(все спаны в одном родителе) или может полнейший бардак?...